# How to include fields of one AVRO schema in another without nesting?

Tags: avro

I would like to create an AVRO schema that uses fields from another schema without creating a nested record. Take the following example:

Schema A:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "example",
  "name": "SchemaA",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to create Schema B which uses the fields from Schema A and adds an additional field, i.e. the result should be:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "example",
  "name": "SchemaB",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to create this Schema B by referencing the fields of Schema A?

Note: I do not want to create a nested field like:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "example",
  "name": "SchemaB",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "SchemaA",
      "type": "example.SchemaA"
    },
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```